# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

It seems to me that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, but $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ isn't? Since, for example, $x+5 \neq x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ but they are equal in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

Is this reasoning correct? If so, how can I formalize it?

Comment: In your opinion, are the ideal generated by $5x$ and the ideal generated by both $5$ and $x$ (taken in in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$) the same?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]$ is a domain but $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ isn't, since $5, x\in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ is nonzero but $5x=0$.

Comment: @user70925 I don't think so, since 5 is not not in $(5x)$, for example.

Comment: @See-WooLee that's an excellent point, i see it now. thanks.

Comment: @jackson5: These ideals being different you get you answer ( basically the counter exemple you made up for answering my hint is exactly what happens, element-wise, in See-Woo Lee's point ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any ring $R$, if you have elements $a,b\in R$ such that $(a)\neq (ab)$ and $(b)\neq (ab)$, then obviously $R/(ab)$ cannot be a domain since it has nonzero zero divisors $a+(ab)$ and $b+(ab)$.

In particular, this is the case when $R$ is a domain and $a,b$ are two nonzero elements, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. 
$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5x)$ is isomorphic to the subring of product ring $\mathbb{F}_5[x]\times\mathbb{Z}$ of pairs $(f(x),n)$ such that $f(0)\equiv 0 \pmod5$

Comment: Could you be explicit about your isomorphism to the subring of $F_5[x]\times \mathbb Z$? I thought you were talking about the natural one, $f+(5x)\mapsto (f+(5),f+(x))$, but that does not match what you're describing. It sounds very similar though: essentially $f+(5x)\mapsto (f\pmod 5, f(0))$.

Comment: I bet you meant to say what I said. What you've currently written can't be correct: the set of such pairs does not form a ring with identity, but the quotient of course does.